# Lock screen custom image gets corrupted on its first update after it gets created

Tags: windows-phone-8, user-controls, windows-phone, lockscreen

I've a Windows Phone 8.0 app and am in the process of developing its lock screen support.

I've created a user control for the lock screen image to be based on. The code to achieve this works flawlessly when first run. That is, when I turn on the lock screen, the lock screen custom image is rendered correctly.

[image]

However, when the lock screen gets updated, the image is not rendered correctly with all elements on top of each other.

[image]

This is the code that creates the lock screen image and is then used to update it:

```
    public async void CreateOrUpdateLockScreen()
{
    try
    {
        try
        {
            var isProvider = Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreenManager.IsProvidedByCurrentApplication;
            if (!isProvider)
            {
                // If you're not the provider, this call will prompt the user for permission.
                // Calling RequestAccessAsync from a background agent is not allowed.
                var op = await Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreenManager.RequestAccessAsync();

                // Only do further work if the access was granted.
                isProvider = op == Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreenRequestResult.Granted;
            }

            if (isProvider)
            {
                // At this stage, the app is the active lock screen background provider.
                var image = new Weathercast.Core.Lockscreen_NowToday();
                image.Measure(new Size(720, 1280));
                image.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, 720, 1280));

                var bmp = new WriteableBitmap(720, 1280);
                bmp.Render(image, null);

                bmp.Invalidate();

                string path = "/Shared/ShellContent/";
                string fileName;

                try
                {
                    var currentImage = Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreen.GetImageUri();

                    if (currentImage.ToString().EndsWith("_A.jpg"))
                    {
                        fileName = "LockScreen_B.jpg";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fileName = "LockScreen_A.jpg";
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    fileName = "LockScreen_A.jpg";
                }


                using (var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    if (!isf.DirectoryExists("/LockScreen"))
                    {
                        isf.CreateDirectory("/LockScreen");
                    }

                    using (var stream = isf.OpenFile(path + fileName, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                    {
                        bmp.SaveJpeg(stream, 720, 1280, 0, 100);
                    }
                }

                Uri uri = new Uri("ms-appdata:///Local" + path + fileName, UriKind.Absolute);

                // Set the lock screen background image.
                Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreen.SetImageUri(uri);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You said no, so I can't update your background.");
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

UPDATE:

This is the xaml of my user control, LockScreen_NowToday, that the lock screen image is based on (note: just showing the overall structure to give an idea, if more detail needed let me know):

```
<UserControl 
x:Class="Weathercast.Core.Lockscreen_NowToday"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="White">


<Border 
    x:Name="LayoutRoot"
    Height="1280" Width="720"
    Margin="0,100,0,0">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="19"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="19"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    ..

    </Grid>

..
</Border>
```

LockScreen_NowToday.xaml.cs:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Controls;


public partial class Lockscreen_NowToday : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /** PROPERTIES **/

    private string[] _temperature = new string[4];
    public string[] Temperature
    {
        get { return _temperature; }
        set
        {
            this._temperature = value;
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Temperature"));
            }
        }
    }

    /** CONSTRUCTOR **/

    public Lockscreen_NowToday()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }


}
```

Comment: Kinda looks like when the redraw happens, it reads the width as a Zero when rendering.  Can you post the `Weathercast.Core.Lockscreen_NowToday()` code?

Comment: Interesting. Updated the original post with its xaml. If you need any more information, let me know. Nothing happens in its constructor.

Comment: Any ideas Chubosaurus Software?

Comment: Could we have the `Weathercast.Core.Lockscreen_NowToday()` code? I bet the issue is as Chubosaurus suggested, that when the app is running in a background thread it's not able to create the control to render it. You may need to create your own image rendering code or find a way to access a UI thread. Maybe try WriteableBitmapEx for the former?

Comment: Updated original post to give a general idea of how Weathercast.Core.Lockscreen_NowToday() works. There are other similar properties used too. The thing to keep in mind is that the mis-rendering doesn't occur when the code is run in the background but if I force refresh the lock screen myself in the foreground. That is, the same code run in the foreground that renders the lock screen image correctly the first time fails to do similarly when I run that same code the second time.

Comment: @Bredcrumbs are you using a `PeriodicTask` to update the screen? If not, how are you updating it?  Just a button Click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the text bunches up it is usually a problem with the layout of the control you are rendering. Try calling UpdateLayout after measure and arrange.

```
WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(Width, Height);
weatherControl.Measure(new Size(Width, Height));
weatherControl.UpdateLayout();
weatherControl.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, Width, Height));
weatherControl.UpdateLayout();

writeableBitmap.Render(tileBackground, null);
writeableBitmap.Invalidate();
```